# How to disable dates dynamically in Ionic datetime?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework

I am having an issue with date-time  in ionic angular v6. I am trying to disable weekends through the entire year. Date-time only allows a selection of days allowed. For example, the issue with this is that if I disable the day 4, December 4th 2021 (Saturday), January 4th, 2022 (Tuesday), etc will be disabled. Is there a way to disable weekends only?
[January 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXdxU.png). [December 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pebbi.png)

Comment: i think best way to achieve that is with getting an event when calender month change, then u can get they year and set the [disabled_part_u_need]="[1,5,9]" or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can add following options, to disable every Saturday and Sunday

```
const options: CalendarModalOptions = {
    disableWeeks: [0, 6] // 0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday
};
```

(Code-Snipped is copied from [here](https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar#disable-weeks))

Then don‘t forget to include this option to your calendar. For more about the options, I refere you to this [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar#calendarcomponentoptions).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried this method before, however, I am trying to restrict specific dates based on the month aka try to catch the event when switched from December to January (using ion-datetime in Ionic v6). For example I want to restrict December 3rd,4th, and 5th and January 12th. Unfortunately this only allows me to restrict days of the week(as you suggested) rather than specific dates dynamically. Please let me know if you have any other ideas!